# Git remote url alias rewrite

Tags: git, git-remote, git-config

I'm working temporarily for a project. I'm using a VPN to connect and mount Windows' folder's git, the working repository to `/mnt/project` and the bare to `/mnt/project-bare`.

I can, from my Ubuntu's local repository, `pull`/`push` to the distant git. However, when I try to `pull`/`push` from the working repository, the URL is not understand by my computer (it's `C:\\Git\\Bare`).

I know I could create another remote and link it to `/mnt/project-bare` but I wouldn't like to change the configuration of the local git, by the way I'm working on it only for a moment.

I would like to know if it's possible to set, like `/etc/hosts` with:

```
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```

but for git's remote' URL :

```
C:\\Git\\Bare /mnt/project-bare
```

In the `git config --global` URL.

Comment: How come the git repo is on a shared drive... You know BitBucket offers free private git repo online?

Comment: This is a client's politic. They prefer to keep it internal.